# FlutterFlow + Firebase error: unable to debug test mobile app related to "Firebase Web Config"

Tags: firebase, flutterflow

I have encountered this error message when trying to test my mobile app:

You need to set "Firebase Web Config" in the Firebase Configuration page to use "Debug Mode"...

Another error message not sure if its related to the issue: "Project uses Firebase Auth (+1 other Firebase features) but Firebase config files are not uploaded."

For your info, I have connected to an existing Firebase database (not generated by FlutterFlow). The structures and rules were not made by me.

Nothing much solutions can be found on google and the FlutterFlow community.

Any ideas guys?